# JQuery to click a button in an iframe

Tags: c#, jquery, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to use the following to click on a button found on a website that I do not have access to the html of.

```
$('#ContentFrame').contents().find('#btnPunch').click();
```

I have been unable to find instructions on how to enable/install/use JQuery commands in a WinForm webBrowser Control.

Please help with this.  Thank you

Comment: I was unable to resolve the issue by using elements in the iFrame.  I chose to control the resolution and size of the webBrowser control and then simulate a mouse click at an x, y coordinate.  Not pretty, but it gets the job done.  Thank you